# Google Calendar push notifications are sent to all participants when one participant responds to an event

Tags: google-api, watch, google-calendar-api

When using Google Calendar API push notification, suppose, sender A sends a meeting invite to B and C. When B accepts the meeting invite, C also receives a push notification. 
This can be problematic in cases where a meeting invite is sent to a lerge number of recipients, say 200 people. In this case each of the 200 recipients of the invite will also see 200 push notifications only due to other recipients accepting or declining the event. 
Is there a way to get push notifications only in case an event's start or end time is changed or event is deleted but not receive push notifications when recipients accept/decline an event?
With Office365 API, I do not see push notifications being sent in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> The Google Calendar API provides [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) that let you watch for changes to resources.

A resource is changed if anything if it is updated or deleted and in this case if a user accepts or declines.

Answer: No you cant pick  You get all the changes you do not get to pick which changes you want. You get notified of all changes on a resource.  I suggest that you filter out the changes that you dont want locally.